# Использование Net.Core библиотек в Net.Framewok

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Возможно ли использование библиотеки написанной в .Net Core в проекте .Net Framework?
Или нужно юзать .Net Standart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, напрямую нельзя. Варианта два:

- писать под .NET Standard, если возможно
- использовать кросс-компиляцию сразу под несколько платформ, VS 2017 поддерживает это из коробки:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

Comment: кросс-компиляция даст несколько бинарников?

Comment: @Grundy да, в Debug/Release появятся соответствующие подпапки.