# Возможно ли подключить библиотеки .NET Framework в .NET Core 2.1.4?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, lib, sfml

Нужно подключить библиотеку в виде DLL, но у меня не получается. Возможно ли это?

Comment: в общем случае нет

Comment: Со 2 версии вы можете ссылаться на .net framework сборки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае нельзя. Например, потому, что .NET Core является подмножеством .NET Framework. Выход: перевести библиотеку на ту версию .NET Standard, которая поддерживает .NET Core.

Многие 3rd party библиотеки потихоньку обзаводятся соответствующии версиями.

**Upd**

Говорят еще, что если библиотека не содержит Windows-specific вызовов, то ее можно зареференсить прямо так. Но я не проверял. Какую библиотеку вы пытаетесь подключить и что именно у вас не получается?

P.S. Ну и заодно привяжу "обратный" вопрос: [Использование Net.Core библиотек в Net.Framewok](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766344/)

Comment: Как можно перенести библиотеку на .NET Standart? Просто переписать её на .NET Core?

Comment: @Editaw5 https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/porting/libraries

Comment: Можно вопрос по ,NET Core, но не по теме вопроса?

Comment: @Editaw5 можно. Справа вверху всегда есть кнопка "Задать вопрос" :).

Comment: пробовал, но это вопрос на который нельзя дать точный ответ.

Comment: @Editaw5 ну отчасти такие вопросы тут тоже разрешены (например, про архитектуру). Его закрыли? Ссылку дадите? Можете попробовать закинуть его в чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--